# Visual Studio 2019 shows github documents modified

Tags: visual-studio

If I open a folder with VS2019 16.8.5 the git property page shows all files from a github folder modified. It is not clear what VS is doing here. All files are created within WSL2 or from linux.

How can this be suppressed?

[image]

The Tools/Options/Documents configuration is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem has something to do with the file mode.
If I do in the repo:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

The problem disappears.